# How can i do to get the list of stopwords using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, stop-words

How can i do to to a get the list of keywords of stopwords in french because my data is in french.
`stop_words=stopwords.words('french')`

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided indicates that you are asking how to use [`nltk`](https://www.nltk.org/)'s stop words. Do I understand what you mean to ask? In this case, the set of stop words is given as follows:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> stop_words = set(stopwords.words('french'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

`NLTK` does offer a stopwords list, but you can take a look at the [stop-words package](https://pypi.org/project/stop-words/#basic-usage). It has 22 languages. The code is very standard to use too.

```
from stop_words import get_stop_words

stop_words = get_stop_words('french')
```